# UpdateMessageAsync doesnt update visiblity timeout

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I got this sample Azure function

```
    [FunctionName("WorkerFunctions")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("outputQueue")]
        CloudQueueMessage item,
        [Queue("outputQueue")]
        CloudQueue outputQueue,
        DateTimeOffset nextVisibleTime,
        DateTimeOffset expirationTime,
        DateTimeOffset insertionTime,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"NextVisibleTime: {nextVisibleTime}");
        log.LogInformation($"NextVisibleTime: {(nextVisibleTime-insertionTime).TotalSeconds}");
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {item.AsString}");
        await outputQueue.UpdateMessageAsync(item,  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), MessageUpdateFields.Visibility);
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

that is backed by this host file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:10",
      "batchSize": 16,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 8
    }
  }
}
```

But the visibility timeout isnt updated to 1 minute it defaults to the 10 seconds that is in the host file.

Am I misunderstanding the UpdateMessageAsync? Or doesnt it work when a message has a lease?

**UPDATE**
The only way for me to get this to work, is to:

1. delete the message
2. add the message again, with the updated timeout

Like this:

```
   [FunctionName("WorkerFunction3")]
    public static async Task Function3(
        [QueueTrigger("outputQueue")]
        CloudQueueMessage item,
        [Queue("outputQueue")]
        CloudQueue outputQueue,
        DateTimeOffset nextVisibleTime,
        DateTimeOffset expirationTime,
        DateTimeOffset insertionTime,
        int dequeueCount,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("########## Function 3 ###############");
        log.LogInformation($"NextVisibleTime: {nextVisibleTime}");
        log.LogInformation($"DequeueCount {dequeueCount}");
        log.LogInformation($"NextVisibleTime: {(nextVisibleTime - insertionTime).TotalSeconds}");
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {item.AsString}");

        item.SetMessageContent(item.AsString + " updated");

        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            await outputQueue.DeleteMessageAsync(item);
            await outputQueue.AddMessageAsync(
                new CloudQueueMessage(item.AsString),
                null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                null,
                null);
        }
    }
```

This is true for both .NET and .NET Core.

I have tried the above, getting a message, and then calling Update, with just a simple console program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials();
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
        CloudQueueClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        var queue = client.GetQueueReference("outputqueue");

        var message = await queue.GetMessageAsync();

        if (message != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.NextVisibleTime);
            await queue.UpdateMessageAsync(message, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), MessageUpdateFields.Visibility);
        }
    }
}
```

And here the timeout is updated properly.

All this smells like the host for Azure Functions is calling update after the exception is thrown, which actually sounds OK in my opinion.

If anyone can anyone point me to the code where this happen here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host I will accept the answer (or give me the actually piece of code to do this properly, if it exists). I am looking myself also.

Comment: Maybe the function runtime overrules my update?

Answer (score 0):

The [CloudQueue.UpdateMessageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.updatemessageasync?view=azure-dotnet) Method **applies to .Net** while your function runtime is v2.

Comment: Oooh. So not core :) I have set the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to ~2

Comment: I sure will. I just want to try the above code in .NET :)

Comment: I doesn't seem to work. I think that my above statement, that the host itself overrides the visibility timeout (because of the thrown exception) even when using .NET.

Comment: The only way I can get this to work is by deleting the message, and adding a new with the delay set to 60 seconds. Both for .NET and .NET Core: https://gist.github.com/mslot/2dc4babdc0bb5714edade2c41d7d32b2

Answer (score 0):

Since the runtime of Azure Functions, https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host "builds upon the tried and true Azure WebJobs SDK - this library just layers on top to allow you to "script the WebJobs SDK"": https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk. If I search through the source code I can see this calling hierarchy:

QueueProcessor - https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Queues/QueueProcessor.cs#L111

1. CompleteProcessingMessageAsync - https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/247a36226a4c1bab445def921d3fb2806c8718b7/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Queues/QueueProcessor.cs#L111
2. if success: DeleteMessageAsync
3. else, ReleaseMessageAsync: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/247a36226a4c1bab445def921d3fb2806c8718b7/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Queues/QueueProcessor.cs#L180

The ReleaseMessageAsync calls UpdateMessageAsync with the provided visibility timeout that is from the config (i think - it looks like it when you traverse the webjobs-sdk). My trailing if the visibilityTimeout ends in the QueueTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.cs.

So it looks like that my assumption about the host runtime overrules my Update is true, when I cast an exception.